# VB.NET and EWS Unread Mail Count caching Exception

Tags: vb.net, exchangewebservices

I have a problem wit some VB.Net code using EWS (Exchange Web Services) to acces a mailbox and count the number of unread mails.
And it works but my problem is that i want to buld in some error handeling eg when wrong login informationen.
When i tets my code with a wrong username i get an ServiceRequestException in this code

```
Dim emails = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, sf, iv)
```

I have tryed with some Try Cach and so on but it docent seems to catch the error.

Hope someone can help me how to catch such an error so my code docent stop and crashe.

```
Try

            Dim service = New ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP1)
            Dim credential As New NetworkCredential("username", "password", "localdomain")
            Dim Url = New Uri("https://mail.mydomain.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx")
            Dim prop As New PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties)

            service.Url = Url
            service.Credentials = credential

            Dim arrSearchFilter(1) As SearchFilter
            arrSearchFilter(0) = New SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(EmailMessageSchema.IsRead, True)
            arrSearchFilter(1) = New SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(EmailMessageSchema.IsRead, False)

            Dim oSearchFilter As SearchFilter = Nothing
            oSearchFilter = New SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.Or, arrSearchFilter)

            Dim oView As ItemView = New ItemView(20)

            Dim iv = New ItemView(5) ' get last 5 emails

            iv.OrderBy.Add(ItemSchema.DateTimeReceived, SortDirection.Descending)

            Dim sf As SearchFilter = New SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.And, New SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(EmailMessageSchema.IsRead, False))

            Dim emails = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, sf, iv)

            tAntal.Text = emails.Count ' Writs the number of unread Mails

Catch
            MsgBox("Error4")
End Try
```

See image for error message.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cy8rl.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the type of Exception you want to catch, and also leave only the line where the Exception is thrown inside the "Try" block:

```
Dim service = New ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP1)
Dim credential As New NetworkCredential("username", "password", "localdomain")
Dim Url = New Uri("https://mail.mydomain.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx")
Dim prop As New PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties)

service.Url = Url
service.Credentials = credential

Dim arrSearchFilter(1) As SearchFilter
arrSearchFilter(0) = New SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(EmailMessageSchema.IsRead, True)
arrSearchFilter(1) = New SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(EmailMessageSchema.IsRead, False)

Dim oSearchFilter As SearchFilter = Nothing
oSearchFilter = New SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.Or, arrSearchFilter)

Dim oView As ItemView = New ItemView(20)

Dim iv = New ItemView(5) ' get last 5 emails

iv.OrderBy.Add(ItemSchema.DateTimeReceived, SortDirection.Descending)

Dim sf As SearchFilter = New SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.And, New SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(EmailMessageSchema.IsRead, False))

Try
    Dim emails = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, sf, iv)
Catch Ex As ServiceRequestException
    MsgBox(Ex.Message)
End Try

tAntal.Text = emails.Count ' Writs the number of unread Mails
```